# Going from Dictionary<int, StringBuilder> To Table-Valued SqlParameter. How?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dictionary, table-valued-parameters

I have code that has a Dictionary defined as:

```
Dictionary<int, StringBuilder> invoiceDict = new Dictionary<int, StringBuilder>();
```

Each Value in each KeyValuePair the Dictionary is actually three separate values currently created as follows:

```
invoiceDict.Add(pdfCount+i, new StringBuilder(invoiceID.Groups[1].ToString() + "|" + extractFileName + "|" + pdfPair.Key));
```

As you can see, the three values are separated by a '|'. The number of "rows" in the Dictionary can range between 600-1200. I would like to use a table-valued parameter to get all of that in my SQL Server 2008 DB in one operation.

The table-valued parameter is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.BatchSplitterInvoices AS TABLE
(
    InvoiceID varchar(24),
    NotePath varchar(512),
    BatchID varchar(50)
)

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.cms_createBatchSplitterInvoices (
  @Invoices dbo.BatchSplitterInvoices READONLY,
  @StaffID int
)
```

What's the best way to get from the Dictionary to something that can be passed into the table-valued param? Should I use something else than the Dictionary? Or, do I need to parse the Dictionary into another, better data structure?

```
SqlParameter invoicesParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Invoices", invoiceDict.Values);
invoicesParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to use a TVP?

Comment: Incidentally, your use of StringBuilder in your example is not useful. You've concatenated the strings as you would normally, passed a single string into the StringBuilder, then returned it. It's more useful to use something like string.Concat with the individual strings as parameters to the function.

Comment: @flesh: No particular reason. I am trying to avoid multiple calls to the DB and wanted to make my client less "chatty". I am investigating this option, as opposed to using multiple params, big SQL strings or awkward XML blocks. Lastly, I can't use SqlBulkCopy because I need to process on the db.

Comment: I've found TVPs to be painfully slow (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071818) - they look like a good solution, but just about every other way is quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to issue with somewhat poor documentation surrounding the TVPs (needs more than just IEnumerable), and having to parse the content of dictionaries anyways, I decided to loop through the Dictionary into a DataTable, which seems to be the preferred object to feed a TVP.

Answer (score 1):

Both @narayanamarthi and @ChrisGessler are on the right track with regards to using the `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` interface instead of a DataTable. Copying the collection to a DataTable is just wasting CPU and memory for no gain. But  the iterator can be separate from the collection.

So some notes:

- Don't use `AddWithValue` when creating `SqlParameter`s. It is just a bad pratice
- Don't concatenate the 3 distinct values that you want in the TVP into a String or StringBuilder. The entire purpose of a TVP is to pass in a strongly-typed record so serializing the fields into a CSV list defeats the purpose. Instead use the Invoice class as recommended by Chris.
- Replace your `invoiceDict.Add(...)` with `List<Invoice>.Add(new Invoice(...));`
- Create a method to iterate over the collection:

  ```
  private static IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> SendRows(List<Invoice> Invoices)
  {
    SqlMetaData[] _TvpSchema = new SqlMetaData[] {
      new SqlMetaData("InvoiceID", SqlDbType.Int),
      new SqlMetaData("NotePath", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512),
      new SqlMetaData("BatchID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
    };
    SqlDataRecord _DataRecord = new SqlDataRecord(_TvpSchema);

    foreach(Invoice _Invoice in Invoices)
    {
      _DataRecord.SetInt32(0, _Invoice.Id);
      _DataRecord.SetString(1, _Invoice.NotePath);
      _DataRecord.SetString(2, _Invoice.BatchId);
      yield return _DataRecord;
    }
  }
  ```
- Declare the parameter as follows:

  ```
  SqlParameter _InvoiceParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Invoices", SqlDbType.Structured);
  _InvoiceParam.Value = SendRows(Invoices);
  ```

---

I have additional notes and links in the following two answers with regards to TVPs in general:

- [How can I insert 10 million records in the shortest time possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770180/how-i-can-insert-10-million-entry-in-shortest-time-possible/25773471#25773471)
- [Pass Dictionary<string,int> to Stored Procedure T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957132/pass-dictionarystring-int-to-stored-procedure-t-sql/25815939#25815939)

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the IEnumerable interface on the class holding your collection and then explicitly implementing the GetEnumerator Method for the IEnemerable will serve the purpose. There is an article at http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/. Please go through this

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` on a custom collection object.  In your case, you should change your `Dictionary<int, StringBuilder>` to `List<Invoice>` or `List<Tuple<int, string, int>>`

For example:

```
class Invoice
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string NotePath { get; set; }
  public int BatchId { get; set; }
}

class InvoiceCollection : List<Invoice>, IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>
{
  IEnumerator<SqlDataRecord> IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>.GetEnumerator()
  {
    SqlDataRecord r - new SqlDataRecord(
      new SqlMetaData("InvoiceId", SqlDataType.Int), 
      new SqlMetaData("NotePath", SqlDataType.VarChar), 
      new SqlMetaData("BatchId", SqlDataType.Int)
    );

    foreach(var item in this)
    {
      r.SetInt32(0, item.Id);
      r.SetString(1, item.NotePath);
      r.SetInt32(2, item.BatchId);
      yield return r;
    }
}
```

Then simply pass the custom list to a `SqlParameter`:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.InvoiceInsUpd", connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter sqlParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Invoices", invoices);
sqlParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
```