# how to insert multiple row of listview into mssqlserver using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

This code is working but I think something is missing because it only works if I add one row at a time. How can I store many rows at a time?

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ZON-PC;Initial Catalog=RestaurantPOSSOC;Integrated Security=True");

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand _sqlcommand = new SqlCommand("insert into OrderInfo (ProductName,Quantity,Price)values('" + listView1.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text + "','" + listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text + "','" + listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text + "')", con);

        SqlDataReader _sqldatareader = _sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
        _sqldatareader.Read();

       con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not need the inner `for()` loop. The foreach will iterate over the entire collection and you can execute an `INSERT` for `item.SubItems[0].Text` and `item.SubItems[1].Text`.

Comment: This is also very insecure and open to sql injection attacks.  You should parameterize your insert.

Comment: And you don't have to open your connection to the database and close it in each loop iteration.

Comment: use bulk insert or if  that doesn't work then insert multiple rows using XML  or create a user type and do it that way.. very simple and lots of existing working example out there on the web..

Comment: what version of SQL server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things I would change for your routine:

1. As gmiley commented, you don't need the foreach loop and the for loop, you are doing n*n inserts this way
2. Connections can be expensive, I would create the connection outside of the foreach loop.
3. When I am doing updates, I use SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery, instead of SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(), since I don't actually expect any rows to come back.

So in pseudocode:

```
using (connection = new(...))
    con.open
    foreach(item)
        command = new command()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    con.close
```

Comment: This is a fairly good sum-up. For completeness, I would include the comments from @Agapwlesu regarding parameterizing the command. This has a number of benefits: 1. Security: by passing values as parameter objects you inherently remove SQL Injection as an attack vector. 2. Data Validation: As a parameter you can enforce data types on incoming values. 3. Readability: Having typed parameters using a standard naming convention will, as a very nice side effect of the other two benefits of parameterized queries, lead to very readable code with little need of comments.

Comment: @gmiley Agreed, but I was trying to limit my answer to the question posed.  While those are important, they take the question to a whole different level that I think OP won't be ready for until understanding how the simpler code works.  OP will need to get to that level, but one step at a time.

Comment: Yep, I just usually find that doing things in line with the .Net framework from the start usually makes your life easier when diagnosing problems like this. So if, by suggestion, I can get someone to refactor to a more proper style of writing, it makes everyone's job a little easier. No need to change your answer, mostly just wanted to have a comment on it to associate it with the other answers/comments, as they aren't answers themselves, but they are correct in content.

Answer (score 0):

Look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query)

basically:
INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but you really should change your starting code to at least this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ZON-PC;Initial Catalog=RestaurantPOSSOC;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();

foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    SqlCommand _sqlcommand = new SqlCommand("insert into OrderInfo (ProductName,Quantity,Price)values('" + item.SubItems[0].Text + "','" + item.SubItems[1].Text + "','" + item.SubItems[2].Text + "')", con);

    SqlDataReader _sqldatareader = _sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
    _sqldatareader.Read();
}

con.Close();
```

And you really also need to parameterize your query and add some exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

First: regardless of what method is used, you *really* need to clean up the external resources. Both the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects have a `.Dispose()` method and should be used in a `using()` construct / macro. The using handles both the `.Dispose()` as well as a basic try / finally to ensure that the `.Dispose()` method is called, even if an error occurs.

Second: if you are using SQL Server 2008 or newer, you should check out Table Valued Parameters (TVPs) as they will eliminate the SQL Injection issues *and* increase performance.

I have examples of doing this in the following answers:

- [Pass Dictionary<string,int> to Stored Procedure T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957132/pass-dictionarystring-int-to-stored-procedure-t-sql/25815939#25815939)
- [How can I insert 10 million records in the shortest time possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770180/how-can-i-insert-10-million-records-in-the-shortest-time-possible/25773471#25773471)

Answer (score 0):

Add this under button click or any, before that you should open a SqlConnection

```
conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString); 

foreach (ListViewItem item in lvPOItem.Items)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO PurchasePOItems (PO_ItemName, PO_Specs, PO_PONumber)values(@PO_ItemName, @PO_Specs,@PO_PONumber)", conn);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PO_ItemName", item.SubItems[0].Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PO_Specs", item.SubItems[1].Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PO_PONumber", cbPurchaseOrderNo.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```